# java.rmi.UnmarshalException with spring ClassNotFound exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, rmi, spring-bean

When I try to run the application, getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/managerBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
```

Associated spring jar files such as `spring.jar, spring-core.jar and spring-beans.jar` are available in the .m2 repository.

Version of spring used is 2.5.5

JDK: 1.6 update 65

Maven: 3.0.4

OS: Mac 10.11.6

Not getting any clue on what could be missing here.

Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Beig 'available in the .m2 directory' doesn't put them on your CLASSPATH.

Comment: After lot of trial and error, same configuration with JDK 1.6U22, worked on my Windows machine. Not sure why it didn't worked on Mac ??

Comment: @EJP, if my eclipse project shows required jar files under maven dependencies does it mean that jars are on class path ?